# MJRTY - A Fast Majority Vote Algorithm isn't work

Tags: algorithms, stream-processing

The MJRTY algorithm sets out to solve the problem of finding the majority element in a stream (an element comprising more than 50% of the stream). Moore proposed to solve this by using only 2 pieces of information and a single scan of the data.
Imagine you have a stream of names (“matt”, “timon”, “matt”, “matt”, “rob”, “ben”, …) and you wanted to know if any name appeared in more than half the stream. Boyer and Moore proposed the following:

```
count = 0
majority = ""

for val in stream:
    if count == 0:
        majority = val
        count = 1
    elif val == majority:
        count += 1
    else:
        count -= 1
print majority if count > 0 else "no majority!"
```

if stream = A A A A B B B B C => result = C, but it isn't truth.

step by step

```
step    val majority    count
0   A   A   1
1   A   A   2
2   A   A   3
3   A   A   4
4   B   A   3
5   B   A   2
6   B   A   1
7   B   A   0
8   C   C   1
```

About this algotithm: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/

Comment: algorithm is positioned as a worker, but as an example see the error

Comment: Your steps 4 through 8 are wrong.  See my answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the algorithm does work.  If you have a new question that is on-topic, make a new post or go to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boyle-Moore algorithm only works if there is a majority, indeed. It is useful if you can assume that there is a majority, for instance when processing binary strings composed of `0` or `1`: if the length of the string is odd, then you must have a majority.

The sequence `A A A A B B B B C` has 9 elements, so you need at least 5 occurences of an element to have a majority, and you don't have it. The result is therefore not significant.

Comment: Are there any linear algorithms that do not have a limit on the "majority"?

Comment: Well yes, you keep a map `value -> count` and increment the `count` each time you see a `value`. You also keep a counter for the length of the input. At the end, divide the length of the input by two, round to the upper integer and see if any `value` has a `count` greater or equal to that value. If there is such an element, it must be only one, obviously.

Comment: This algorithm shows the response, if available, but does not show the absence of a response.

Comment: Well no: if you can't locate such an element, then you don't have a majority.

Comment: map (value -> count) - can be very large for large flow

Comment: Yes, that's an issue that you can't avoid. Another possibility would be rescanning the input to verify if the result of the BM algorithm is actually a majority. So if you got `C`, you read again the stream and count the occurences of `C` to verify that they are at least 50%+1 of the stream. Unfortunately, this requires reading again the input, which is not always possible. For instance, if you are reading an on-line socket stream, you can't replay it unless you store it in a buffer, which will be even more memory-consuming, or on disk, which will be dead-slow.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I had to know that the algorithm does not work properly with this example, I thought I made a mistake somewhere.
The fact that I have not seen mention that there is a necessary condition for "the presence of the majority."

Answer (score 0):

```
Input          count          majority
A                1              A
A                2              A
A                3              A 
A                4              A
B                3              A
B                2              A
B                1              A
B                0              A
C                1              C
```

Count is not greater than 0.  "no majority!"

Comment: I add steps into my question. You forget about '''if count == 0:'''

Comment: You got the last-but-one step wrong: count is `0`, so the majority is still `A` and the variables are updated in the last iteration as `C 1 C`.

Comment: No, `C 1 C`. Run the code from the OP with an extra `print` if you don't believe me :)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Yes, yes.  It's early, and I haven't had my coffee yet.